# How do I know if a client has a community license?

Tags: community

A client informs me that they bought community licenses. How do I verify that? Can this be done in sandbox and production?

Thanks

Comment: have you looked under company information in your org?  you should see user licenses and usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Setup, Search for Company Information in the Quick Find Box
(or under Administer -> Company Profile -> Company Information).

On the Company Information Page there should be a section titled 'User Licenses' with a list below.
Look for the type of license they purchased, for community it will probably be along the lines of 'Customer Community' or 'Customer Community Plus.'

You should be able to verify they are active, how many there are total, how many are used, and when they expire.

You can find this information in both sandbox and production orgs and you do not need to be an admin to see the license information.

You can also find the usage-based community member information on the Company Information page under the 'Usage-based Entitlements' header.